# Should I use all the pins from 1 Port or few from each available (STM32)?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, port

I am using a MCU from the ST, specifically from the STM32L1xx series. I want to connect 2 sensors, both of which will use the I2C protocol, 1 MicroSD card with SPI and 4 Interrupts. Is it a good practice to use as many pins from one port (for example from PORTA) as possible or to use every available port? Some pins connected to PORTA, some to PORTB etc.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

The pins that can be used by the SPI, I2C and interrupt hardware might constrain your selection of pins.

The layout of your board might also influence the pin selection.

For (relatively) high output currents (generaly not a good idea IMO) some chips have a per-port limit, which would favour choosing pins for higher current outpust from different ports.

(copied from Jeroen3's answer) When you are *very* current-starved it might be good to disable unused ports, which can favours using pins in already used ports.

When you must quickly copy a multi-bit value to a number of pins, it will be much easier when those pins are on one port (and even easier when they are conseqeutive and start from bit 0).

Other than those aspects, I don't see how it makes any significant difference which pin you choose, from the same or different ports.

Comment: Lxx devices are usually used in the very low power devices where every uA counts. So enabling the GPIOs without the real need is just a bad design.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 I don't agree with such absolutes: everything depends on the circumstances. But the point indeed deserves mentioning. And I added another - but totally unrelated - reason to favour using bits in one port.

Comment: He is asking about Lxx uC. Lxx uCs are low power and used in the low power designs (otherwise it is not very logical to use more expensive ones if you can have cheaper & faster  Fxx). So I assume that OP is using brain when chooses the uC. If yes - for low power designs - enable as few as possible peripherals as any enabled consumes some uA/MHz just to power its own electronics.

Answer (score 1):

If you goal is to save the 5 uA/MHz by not enabling a GPIO bank, than yes.
Otherwise, just let the peripheral usage board design dictate which IO to use.

Answer (score 1):

You probably design a low power device (Lxx series) and every enabled peripheral (like another GPIO port) consume some current just to drive the internal electronics.  And that is the main reason why very low power devices designers should try to do not enable anything which is not 100% necessary.

Answer (score 0):

From a technical perspective there's no need to use all pins from one port or distribute between all ports. One reason could be if you have a lot of current driving pins, but in most cases the board layout defines where your periphery is connected and therefore defines the ports. In other cases you want to compute parallel data (e.g some buttons) and then it's easier to have them on one port as this simplifies the code.

And of course, if you use special functions of certain pins, they're also defined.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have assigned all hardware IPs to ports that fit your needs, you are left with a bunch of I/Os for other GPIO-related stuff. Most important of them is IRQ lines.

STM32L1 has an external interrupt controller (EXTI) that forces you to only have one pin numbered N among all ports as interrupt. (I.e. you cannot use B0, C0, ... as IRQ if A0 is IRQ, etc.). When you merge this constraint with you PCB routing constraint, using as little ports as possible is a plus, but may not be possible.